# rasa_nlu and rasa_core are deprecated, just installing rasa will work?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I am new to rasa, i have watched some old training videos on youtube and other sources. There they have told to install rasa_nlu and rasa_core.

But when i check on rasa website, it says just to install "rasa" not but "rasa_nlu" and "rasa_core". I am assuming rasa_core and rasa_nlu are deprecated. So just installing rasa will work right?

No need to install rasa_core and rasa_nlu separately?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, just installing rasa will work.

You no longer need to install these parts separately: rasa core and nlu were merged in 2019 (see announcement [here](https://forum.rasa.com/t/merging-rasa-core-and-nlu-repositories)).